# How to disable blocking cursor when dragging elements?

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am implementing a "drag & drop" functionality inside of a small webpage, however, I am having an interface issue.

Whenever I attempt to drag an element that has its `draggable` property set to `true`, the browser displays a *blocking-icon* next to the element.

Below is an image that helps to demonstrate the issue:

[image: Blocking icon on drag attempt]

**Does anyone know how to change that icon, or is it UN-resolvable?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #dropzone {
            background-color: #eee;
            border: 1px dashed #aaa;
            max-width: 200px;
            padding: 100px;
            -webkit-user-drag: auto;
        }
        .draggable {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: burlywood;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<div id="dropzone">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><b>Dropzone</b><br>Drag anything over here</p>
</div>
<div class="draggable" id="o1" draggable="true">Object 1</div>
<div class="draggable" id="o2" draggable="true">Object 2</div>
<script>
    window.ondragstart = function(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
    }
    
    var dropzone = document.querySelector('#dropzone');

    dropzone.ondragover = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
        // this.innerHTML = '';
        this.appendChild(document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')));
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create some code snippet which presents the problem?

Comment: wait... I'll just create it...

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I just added the code..

Comment: on Chrome mac-os I can not reproduce this problem (is see "plus" icon instead "block")

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Is there any way to change this default behaviour of the browser?

Comment: Or do I have to do a workaround using ```mousedown```, ```mouseup``` and other mouse events?

Comment: blocking icon means you do not accept drop there, does a plus icon any better in this case?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, you have displayed no code, nor have you provided any information about your previous attempts to research this issue.

Comment: @appleapple Surely no :) I just want to remove any appearing icon and show the default pointer instead....